# What is the best strategy to backup Google Compute Engine? I have a single box now which is running wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I am running a google compute engine for a wordpress site of mine. The site is storing several user data.

What is the best backup strategy?

Answer (score 0):

GCE supports backups from their interface - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery/backing-up